# Conditional javascript for Google Map values

Tags: javascript, google-maps, conditional-statements

I'm passing some variables to my google maps scrip to output an address in an info window. The variables are being pulled from a database, but not all of them will always exist. Using the following code I sometimes end up with multiple `<br>` tags in a row, meaning I get awkward breaks in the content.

So my question is how do I make it conditional so that only the variables that exist will display, followed by a `<br>`?

```
var contentString = '<div id="map_info">'+
                    '<h4>' + gmapsstring.gmapaddressname + '</h4>'+
                    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                    '<p>' + gmapsstring.gmapaddressstreet + '<br>' +
                    gmapsstring.gmapaddressline2 + '<br>' +
                    gmapsstring.gmapaddressline3 + '<br>' +
                    '<span class="gmap_postcode">' + gmapsstring.gmapaddresspostcode + '</span></p>'+
                    '</div>';
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `length` property of the variables, so you'd have something like:

```
var contentString = '<div id="map_info">';
if( gmapsstring.gmapaddressname.length > 0 ) {
   contentString += '<h4>' + gmapsstring.gmapaddressname + '</h4>';
}
```

and so on. Or even better, you can loop through the properties, using a similar code.